# Python 3 - Type error when connecting to DB via psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

When using the `connect` method of the psycopg2 library, I am mind-boggled on the reason I'm getting the error that the method takes *"0 positional arguments but 1 were given."* Both of the variations of the code below produced the error:

```
psycopg2.connect("dbname=daniellee host=localhost")
psycopg2.connect("dbname='daniellee' host='localhost'")
```

Here's the traceback:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 psycopg2.connect("dbname='daniellee' host='localhost'")
>
> TypeError: connect() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

I have also tried passing in a set of variables and values as shown below, which produced an error stating, *"unexpected keyword argument 'dbname'."*

```
psycopg2.connect(dbname='daniellee', host='localhost')
```

None of these errors make sense because these code snippets adhere to the syntax as outlined psycopg2 documentation. I've been trying to get this to work for a few hours now to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Are you sure you've imported `psycopg2` correctly, and that `psycopg2.connect` is the method you think it is?

Comment: In your second attempt, ```psycopg2.connect(dbname='daniellee', host='localhost')```, "dbname" should be "database" as it is a keyword argument and not a connection string item.

Comment: @Alasdair, I've added the traceback.

Comment: @Martin, I have tried that too, but it did not work.

Comment: What version of psycopg2 are you using?

Comment: @kat, 2.7.3.2 and 3.6 Python

Comment: I would check that you are importing psycopg2 correctly and you have somehow called the wrong thing, monkeypatched something, or somehow changed your psycopg2 connect. Try starting an iPython session do an import psycopg2 then do the connect and make sure you can connect outside your code.